# C++ Need help accessing values inside of linked list

Tags: c++, list, segmentation-fault

```
class Node {
public:
    Node();
    void setNext(Node*);

private:
    void* item;
    Node* next;
};

void Node::setNext(Node* n)
{
    next = n;
}

class List {
public:
    List();
    void addFirst(void*);
    void reset();
    void* getCurItem();

private:
    Node* head;
    Node* current;
};

void List::addFirst(void* obj)
{
   Node *newNode = new Node(obj);
   newNode->setNext(head);
   head = newNode;
}

void List::reset()
{
   current = head;
}

void* List::getCurItem()
{
    return current->getItem();
}


Polynomial::Polynomial(std::ifstream& input){
    List *polyCo = new List();
    List *polyEx = new List();

    bool exit = false;
    double coefficient=0;
    int exponent=0;

    while(!exit && input.good()){

    input >> coefficient;

            if(coefficient != -9999.99){

            input >> exponent;
            cout << "Exponent before: " << exponent << endl;
            cout << "Coefficient before: " << coefficient << endl;
            int *ExPtr =  &exponent;
            double *CoPtr  =  &coefficient;

            cout << "Exponent: " << *(ExPtr) << endl;
            cout << "Coefficient: " << *(CoPtr) << endl;
            polyCo->addFirst(ExPtr);
            polyEx->addFirst(CoPtr);
            cout << polyCo->getCurItem() << endl; //SEG FAULT
            }
   }

  polyEx->reset();
  polyCo->reset();

}
```

I am reading numbers from a file into two separate linked lists. I am getting a segmentation fault when attempting to access the value in either of the linked list.

First, I'm going to outline how I think my addFirst() functions works, because I could just be implementing it incorrectly. When addFirst() is called, a new node is created, and the data being read in is set equal to the member of the new node. The existing node in the list is pushed forward, and the new node created becomes the head. The two nodes are also linked.

There could be something else entirely wrong besides my implementation of the function, but at least it is a good place to start, along with the source of the segmentation fault.

Comment: There seems to be multiple posts here on SO about this `Polynomial` class which really has nothing to do with writing a Polynomial class, but has to do with linked lists.  Why do you need `List*` in your `Polynomial` class, when all you need is `List`?  Why isn't `List` safely copyable and assignable, i.e. follow the "Rule of 3"?

Comment: The list is used to hold varying degrees of values of a polynomial. So, one list represents the coefficients in ascending order, while the other List represents the exponents. I probably don't need to use List for this assignment, except for the fact that its a stipulation for the assignment. Also, I don't understand your point about it being safely copyable and assignable.

Comment: Your `Polynomial` class itself should have `List` members (not pointers).  In addition, your `Polynomial` constructor has memory leaks since those pointers you're using are local, you allocate memory and assign to them, and then the function returns without deallocating or storing those pointers anywhere for later deletion.  But this is irrelevant -- you should be testing your `List` class in a small `main` program that calls the `List` functions to ensure they work properly **before** you start using it in "real" work.